# Ordering of tags in XML documentation

Tags: c#, .net

Microsoft have the triple-slash XML documentation with their [recommended set of tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx).

It would be weird if the ordering of the tags were different in different places where they were used.

So I am wondering if there is any recommended ordering for the XML tags?

Example:

```
/// <summary>Performs a foo calculation.</summary>
/// <param name="baseValue">The base value.</param>
/// <param name="af">The amplification factor.</param>
/// <returns>The supposed calculation.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><paramref name="af"/> is negative.</exception>
/// <remarks>According to the theory laid forward by Dr. Hans Foo in 1732.</remarks>
/// <example>
/// Performs a foo calculation using a amplification factor of 10.
/// <code>var value = Foo(512, 10);</code>
/// </example>
public decimal Foo(int baseValue, decimal af) { /* ... */ }
```

Right now, I only assume that the `<summary>` tag always ought to be the first tag.

Comment: Their main purpose is as metadata that is picked up by Visual Studio to give better intellisense help, so under normal use the order doesn't matter. Obviously in your codebase you might care. Maybe internally you could standardise on what GhostDoc does: http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

Comment: @satnhak Admittedly I didn't try very hard but, I did not find any recommended ordering at your '_ghostdoc_' link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After browsing [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3Aaspnet%20summary&type=Code&ref=searchresults), a pattern began to emerge and the following informal order of tags seems to be pretty common:

1. `summary`
2. `typeparam`
3. `param`
4. `returns`
5. `exception`
6. `remarks`
7. `example`

Other observations:

- The words `true`, `false` and `null` tend to be wrapped within the `<c>` tag.
- Sometimes but not always URLs are within the `<c>` tag.
- References to types are marked up with the `<see cref="Foo"/>` tag.
- References to generic types are marked up with `<see cref="Bar{T}"/>` tag.
- References to parameters are marked up with the `<paramref name="name"/>` tag.
- References to generic type parameters are marked up with the `<typeparamref name="T"/>` tag.
- Sentences end with punctuation.
- Nested tags, such as `<code>` within an `<example>`, are sometimes indented.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no official XML Schema for the XML documentation generated by these inline documentation statements (cf. [XSD for XML documentation generated for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188900/xsd-for-xml-documentation-generated-for-c)), so the probably best answer is that whether or not the order makes a difference depends on what you want to do with that XML documentation. To my knowledge, most documentation generators will not make a difference in the order and neither does IntelliSense.

Apart from the technological consequence, I agree that it might be helpful to have some code guideline to comply with, but I also haven't heard of a well accepted one.

So in short, I don't think there is a recommended ordering, as the order will not make a difference, but you are free to create an internal guideline.